# Which UK Visa for attending a short training course?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I have just completed college and do not yet have a job. Now I am planning to attend a short training for 5 days in the UK. The trip would be of around 10 days as I also plan to visit some places there as well.

I will be sponsored by my parents and going alone. I have received an acceptance letter from the organizer of the training. So should I apply for a general visit visa (tourist) or short academic visa (< 6 months)? I read on the UKVI website and it says that if the training/course is under 30 days then the tourist visa would do. But I've already got one rejection when I applied for the tourist visa and the reason was that the source of funds in bank accounts was not justified. I think it was because my parents transferred funds to my account recently for the purpose of trip and before that there were not much in my personal account as I rarely use it. So please suggest how to get the visa approved?

Some travel agents have told me to not mention about the course and apply as if going for a holiday, that way it is more likely to get the visa. As like any other general citizen I don't have any intentions to overstay and would return at the end of my trip but how to prove that formally to the visa officer since my college ID validity has expired and I have not got a job. I am 23 and live in Jaipur, India.

Comment: You are asking several question. For the last rejection: if your parent sponsor your travel, you should show your parent bank statements, or something that proof that they can afford your travel. If you never worked, how can your account proof you can afford it?  I think you are looking the question from the wrong point of view. Check last rejection and correct. You will find in this site a lot of comment about how to prove financial means

Comment: If you don’t have a job, can’t finance the trip yourself, and already have one refusal, you’re likely to get another IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for a tourism visa.

You can do all the things under [Appendix 3](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) which include:

> ## Study
>
> 25 Visitors may carry out the following study:
>
> - (a) educational exchanges or visits with a state funded school or academy or independent school; or
> - (b) a maximum of 30 days study on:
> - (i) recreational courses (not English language training);
> - **(ii) a short-course (which includes English language training) at an accredited institution;**

Therefore you should apply for a tourism visa and you don’t need to mention the course.

Comment: The UK Visitor visa application asks about the trip purpose / itinerary. If the activity the OP plans to undertake is allowed, why no need to mention the course? Arguably a better premise than just tourism, especially given the previous refusal